# Deleted JavaVM.framework, how to restore?

Tags: macos, java

I accidentally deleted `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework`, and now i can't use any command like `java, javac, etc..` even if i have java installed. So someone know how to restore this folder (no, i do not have time machine configured)? Or know to do some workarounds to java keep working again on command line?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally deleted `JavaVM.framework` as well. After some googling I came across [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208465/558700) to a similar question on StackOverflow. Thanks to that answer I was successful in restoring the framework from the JavaDeveloper dmg you can find at the Apple Developer site (it is probably available elsewhere, but direct from the source seemed like a good way to go).

Comment: I reinstalled all my OS because i couldn't find any solutions for my problem. But i will keep this in mind, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall jdk for mac os.
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-JDK-(Java-Development-Kit)-on-Mac-OS-X

The download package is java_for_os_x rather than jdk-macosx from oracle website.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting contents in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and re-installing java

Comment: Doesn't work :(